# use Table data type in a local variable in a sql server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a data type  as a TABLE but I can't use it in a local variable in my stored procedure (SQln Server 2008)

```
Create type myTableDataType as table
(
    field1 int,
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(100)
)   

create Procedure myStoredProcedureTest
as
begin
declare @temporaltable as  myTableDataType 

.
.
.
.
end
```

in my declare sentence I got ann error `"variable has an invalid data type"`

Some idea where I'm wrong!!!

Thanks

Elaina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [table variable:](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1556/differences-between-sql-server-temporary-tables-and-table-variables/)

```
create Procedure myStoredProcedureTest
as
begin
declare @temporaltable as table
(
    field1 int,
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(100)
)    

.
.
.
.
end
```